# HTC People Widget: Changing Pictures

Tags: contacts, htc-evo, app-widgets

Is there any way to change or set the source for the pictures on the People Widget when you have linked contacts?

Example: I have my wife as one of my contacts.  I have her Facebook/Twitter accounts linked to my entries for my GMail and Exchange contacts. I've added a picture taken by the on phone camera to the Exchange contact entry but the widget uses her Facebook profile picture as the display picture.

Any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From the widget, select the contact name (not image). This brings you to the contact info. Select the chain link in the upper right hand corner (it should say Linked in your specific example). Finally, select the image in the upper left corner. You can select the image source from there. I tested it on the HTC incredible.

**EDIT:** I was originally referring to the Favorites Widget but basically, the Favorites Widget is just an example of the People widget which can be the any-group-at-all widget.

(I apologize if this is obvious, caffeine has not fully sunk in yet.)