# How do I stop Facebook linked contacts' pictures from automatically updating from Facebook?

Tags: contacts, facebook

I have several contacts with linked Facebook accounts.  I've set contact pictures for them using Google Contacts, but every time they update their Facebook profile picture, the Facebook picture is selected automatically.

When this happens, I need to go back and change manually back to the picture I selected myself, which gets pretty annoying.

How do I prevent Facebook (or other linked account) pictures from taking over?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/htc-people-widget-changing-pictures

Comment: These appear to be the opposite problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7277/how-do-i-prod-my-droid-2-into-resyncing-facebook-profile-pictures http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8812/how-to-update-the-picture-of-my-contact-from-facebook-in-htc-wildfire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your home screen, under `Menu->Settings->Accounts&sync->Facebook` you can uncheck `Contacts`. Obviously, this will stop your phone contacts from syncing to facebook, but after you get the list the first time, the only thing that really updates is the pictures, so disabling it should take care of it :)

Comment: This seems to have done the trick.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no Menu->Settings->Accounts&sync option in Android 4.1.2. Any other options?